# Updating google sheet after clicking button and submit

Tags: javascript, html

this is an application where the teacher marks the attendance by clicking the buttons,I want all the buttons to be clicked and turned green for the present after clicking, and then submitting all the data together into the excel sheet on click of submit button

```
<script>
    function handleClick(buttonId) {
      var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
      if (button.value === "Absent") {
        button.value = "Present";
        button.style.backgroundColor = "green"; // set button color to green
      } else {
        // ask for confirmation before changing value to "Absent"
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to mark this as absent?")) {
          button.value = "Absent";
          button.style.backgroundColor = ""; // reset button color to default
        }
      }
      console.log("Button value:", button.value);
    }
  </script>
```

I want the teacher to select all the students who are present and at the end click submit

which of the buttons are correct?
Suggest correct way

```
<body style="background-color:powde;">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <h1><span class="highlight">Smart</span> Attendance System</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><a href="inex.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">login</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <h1 style="color:white">Welcome to attendance system </h1>
  <div>
    <form autocomplete="off" method="POST"
      action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyfIqVWX3a0ORtpzkEJU2cTAjmU1mDWoZ3vioBN7dvcNTT24A_IY9xG2CzfPyY3ULQ4sA/exec">
      <label for="Name">prof</label>
      <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="jayesh jagtap">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="Sub">Sub:</label>
      <input type="text" id="sub" name="sub" placeholder="Microprccesor">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="Date">Date:</label>
      <input type="text" id="Date" name="Date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">

      <h2 style="text-align:center">Click on student roll no who is present</h2>

      <label for="st_1"></label>      
      <button type="button" name="st_1" id="bt1" value="Absent" onclick="handleClick('bt1')">
        <input type="button" value="01" class="button_1">
      </button>
      
      <label for="st_2"></label>        
      <button type="button" name="st_2" id="bt2" value="Absent" onclick="handleClick('bt2')">
        <input type="button" value="02" class="button_1">
      </button>

      <button type="submit" class="button_1" name="st_3" id="bt3" value="Absent"
        onclick="handleClick('bt3')">03</button>
      <button type="submit" class="button_1" name="st_4" id="bt4" value="Absent"
        onclick="handleClick('bt4')">04</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_1" name="st_5" id="bt5" value="Absent"
        onclick="handleClick('bt5')">05</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_1" name="st_6" id="bt6" value="Absent"
        onclick="handleClick('bt6')">06</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_1" name="st_7" id="bt7" value="Absent"
        onclick="handleClick('bt7')">07</button>
```

```
<button type="button" class="button_1" name="st_74" id="bt74" value="Absent"
        onclick="handleClick('bt74')">74</button>
      <hr>

      <button type="submit" class="sub">SUBMIT </button>



    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I want when all the "Present" students roll number buttons are clicked, they must turn green, and then with a single click od submit button, every student attendance should be updated in the google sheet